# How to run java file when file is not created

Tags: java

I have a question on how to run a java file that I had downloaded from my professor. The problem occurs when I open eclipse and open the java file from where I had it saved eclipse will not let me run the java file.

Comment: if that java file has `main`, then `javac fileName.java`(compile) and `java ClassName`(Run)

Answer (score 2):

Create a new project and then import the file to this new project ,finally run the project as application.

Answer (score 0):

why not use javac and java commands on cmd line?. In eclipse, you could also add the file to an existing project and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just copy and paste the contents if it is just a matter of one file.